# Was ist der Staudenreiter?

Tags: meaning

Es ist eine Lust, im Grimm‘schen Wörterbuche zu stöbern und dabei der vielen Bedeutungen gewahr zu werden, welche ein Wort wie *hecken* haben mag! Auf eben diesem Wege, stieß ich auf das Wort *[Heckenfischer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GH04709#XGH04709)*, das den Strauchdieb meint. Dort aber liest man:

> mit ganz anderen gefühlen blickt der freie bewohner des (Bündner) landes zu diesen vesten auf. meist der geschichte unkundig sieht er sie nur als kettenhäuser und zwingburgen der vorzeit an, als die horste schuldbelasteter wegelagerer, gewaltthätiger zwingherren und ritterlicher missethäter, schnapphähne, heckenfischer, staudenreiter. Kohl Alpenreisen 2 (1849) 120.

Dabei ist *Staudenreiter* ein Wort, welches ich weder im Grimm noch sonst irgendwo habe finden können! Es liegt die Vermutung nahe, es bezeichne - ähnlich wie *Schnapphahn* und *Heckenfischer* – einen Dieb, zumal einen berittenen. Doch habe ich mit dergleichen Vermutungen schon falsch gelegen und bitte daher um Ihre Hilfe!

Was ist der *Staudenreiter*? Wo war oder ist das Wort gebräuchlich?

---

Comment: Erstes Ergebnis in der Google-Suche nach Staudenreiter [link](https://books.google.de/books?id=afFPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=staudenreiter&source=bl&ots=Qw_nQqekNx&sig=vI26Ug3qazZeV45ZKgwCEmGooBo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiawaSf1q_YAhVH5aQKHeeqADMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=staudenreiter&f=false) . "_Die Staudenreiter, welche sonst die Wege unsicher machten und die man ohne viele Umstände durch einen Strick beförderte, hatten sich allerdings sehr vermindert, aber die Reichsfürsten fanden weit wirksamere Weisen, um den Handel jetzt für sich auszubeuten._" Also ein anderes Wort für Räuber.

Comment: @mtwde oh! Machen sie eine Antwort daraus! Ich habe nur Humbug ergooogled

Comment: "search instead for staudenreiter" anklicken. Bei sehr ungebräuchlichen oder leicht falschen Wörtern geht google davon aus, dass man sich verschrieben hat und zeigt Suchergebnisse für die wahrscheinlichste Variante an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie bereits in meinem Kommentar geschrieben führt eine Google-Suche nach dem Begriff zu folgendem [Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=afFPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=staudenreiter&source=bl&ots=Qw_nQqekNx&sig=vI26Ug3qazZeV45ZKgwCEmGooBo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiawaSf1q_YAhVH5aQKHeeqADMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=staudenreiter&f=false).

> Die Staudenreiter, welche sonst die Wege unsicher machten und die man
>   ohne viele Umstände durch einen Strick beförderte, hatten sich
>   allerdings sehr vermindert, aber die Reichsfürsten fanden weit
>   wirksamere Weisen, um den Handel jetzt für sich auszubeuten.

Alternativ noch folgender [Text](https://www.dlib.si/stream/URN:NBN:SI:DOC-WMAFBHBB/ab7071d9-a635-4cc7-b30b-e668375ba732/TEXT) an anderer Stelle

> Die rhatischen Ritter. Wegelagerer, gewaltthatiger Zwingherren und
>   ritterlicher Missethäter. „Schnapphähne", „Heckenfischer",
>   „Staudenreiter", vor deren Raublust und Fehdesucht einst weder Volk
>   noch Kirche sich des Rechts und Besitzes habe erfreuen können

Ein Staudenreiter ist also aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach ein anderes altes Wort für einen Räuber/Wegelagerer/Strauchdieb, der Reisende überfiel.

Weitere Details zur Vorsilbe Staude und Wortverwandschaften [hier](https://fwb-online.de/lemma/staude.s.1f)

Aus welchem räumlichen Bereich das Wort stammt kann vielleicht noch jemand anderes beisteuern.

Answer (score 2):

Versuch mal 
[Woerterbuchnetz.de](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/setupStartSeite.tcl)

da kann mann alle deutschen Wörterbücher nachsehen.

Es gibt da einen Eintrag: Stūde(n)rīter* im Schweizerisches Idiotikon digital - Band VI

[Stūde(n)rīter*](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id6.htm#!page/61705/mode/1up) -> Kunstreiter - "der von einen Pferd aufs andere springt"?

Comment: Ein Kunstreiter dürfte wohl eher nicht gemeint gewesen sein.